# wsl command doesn't have --set-version option in Windows

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to install new version of WSL meant WSL2 according to the installation instructions documented by Microsoft but the `wsl` command doesn't have `--set-version` option in my PowerShell to complete instructions while the WSL Ubuntu 18.04 is already been installed. I ran PowerSell as administrator in my windows 10 build 1903. How can i fix this? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: According to https://www.ghacks.net/2019/06/13/microsoft-drops-windows-subsystem-for-linux-2-in-latest-windows-10-20h1-build/, version 1903 doesn't have WSL 2 yet, only insider builds.

Comment: Oh! You are right. I didn't care about that. Thank you